# Avoid line break between minus sign and amount

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm generating a pdf using FOP.

Due to the box width constraint, the message *"Balance of -$578.09 from your previous bill"* is split into two lines, with the minus sign at the end of the first line and the amount at the beginning of the second line.

**Input:**

```
<fo:block>Balance of -$578.09 from your previous bill</fo:block>
```

**Output:**

```
Balance of -
$578.09 from.
```

**How can I keep together the value in the message?**

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **keep property** to ensure that the minus sign is not considered a feasible position for a line break:

```
<fo:block>
    Balance of 
    <fo:inline keep-together="always">-$578.09</fo:inline> 
    from your previous bill
</fo:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using `<fo:block text-align="justify">`.

Comment: While this actually (or *strangely*) works with FOP, it is not guaranteed to work with other formatters.

Comment: Agreed, it works only as a side effect of the combination of box width and text width.